# PushPlugin WP8 onclick event

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am developing a WP8 cordova application with pushnotification(toast)

Everything is working fine, but i cannot find an event for when the user taps on a notification (onopen or something like that).

For android and ios there is e.coldstart and e.foreground but windows doesn't have this.

Can someone help me out here?

Thank you all.

Edit: found this as exactly the same issue; https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/431